# how to access a F# method that doesn't have any arguments from C#?

Tags: c#, f#

let's consider these two methods:

```
let AA value =
    value

let BB =
    string DateTimeOffset.Now
```

if I call them in C#:

```
var a = test.AA(3); // no problem
var b = test.BB(); <- this doesn't compile
```

how can I call parameter-less methods from C#?

Comment: `let BB = string DateTimeOffset.Now` isn't a method, it's an assignment. `let BB () = string DateTimeOffset.Now` would be a method.

Comment: ahh ok, I get it. I'm at my 2nd attempt at getting into F# :) so the () force it to be a method, however the parenthesis are not put when there are parameters? so would let AA (value) be considered correct? following the same syntax

Comment: The parenthesis essentially mean that the function accepts Unit as an input, and returns _something_. It wouldn't be idiomatic to use parenthesis around the parameters of another function, and it may cause them to be interpreted as a Tuple deconstruction. This does tie in when you call C# methods from an F# program though, where you actually pass the parameters to the method as a Tuple `(param1, param2, paramN)`, which just happens to look like a normal C# method call.

Comment: The `()` are actually an argument - the only value of the `unit` type. A function always needs to have at least one argument, and when there are no useful arguments to pass, the `()` value is generally used.

Comment: ok, after reading about the unit type, it now all makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BB` in your example isn't a function, it's a value. It's being computed once on module initialization (and module is a static class under the hood).

What you need is to pass a `unit` there, which looks like this:

```ml
let BB() =
    string DateTimeOffset.Now
```

Not it's a function/method.